# How to run cprofile with already a -m existing in command line?

Tags: python, command-line, cprofile

Usually if you have a script foo.py you can easily profile it as follows:

```
python -m cProfile foo.py
```

However let's imagine I am already running foo as a module with -m:

```
python -m path.foo
```

In this case is there a clean way to profile this execution? I have tried:

```
python -m cProfile -m path.foo
```

Clearly it did not work but you get what I am trying to do so how do I do it?